# What's the unicode for the Share icon (or do I need to use SVG instead)?

Tags: icon, social-sharing-buttons, unicode, sharing, utf-8

A commonly recognised [share icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_icon) looks like this:

[image: Share Icon]

I'm guessing there must be (surely) a Unicode symbol out there for this, but so far - despite pretty thorough searching - I've come up empty-handed.

I note that [the approved list of new emojis for 2020](https://blog.emojipedia.org/117-new-emojis-in-final-list-for-2020/) include:

- a dodo
- a rollerboot
- a rainbow piñata

I'm concluding it's unlikely that Unicode would have got as far as approving these but not yet approving a **share icon**.

What's the Unicode for the share icon above, please?

*Or do I need to use SVG, instead?*

Comment: I am not aware of an existing one, nor could I find one. You may go ahead and [submit it](https://www.unicode.org/pending/proposals.html)!

Comment: There are some nice public domain SVG easily available. You may want to minifiy them before using in a production environment (I tested and got a 44% reduction in size).

Comment: Thanks, @Éric. I'll probably use this one: [Share Icon 2](https://github.com/RouninMedia/shodou/blob/master/user-interface/share2.svg) - it's 721 bytes.

Comment: U+2056 is three dots but without any connecting lines: ⁖

Comment: Ah, that's helpful, @StephenOstermiller, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358594/is-there-a-unicode-character-for-the-share-icon

Comment: Thanks, @Steve - yes I saw that before posting the question above, but it's from 2014 and (apparently) off-topic for Stack Overflow. (One of the reasons why I posted here at SE Webmasters, instead). I figured that even though there was no available answer in 2014, there might be an answer now in 2020.

Comment: *"I'm concluding it's unlikely that Unicode would have got as far as approving these but not yet approving a share icon."* Ironically, you are wrong. The Unicode Consortium is totally dropping the ball! As a developer I am totally frustrated that they actually are literally doing what you are saying: adding rainbow pirate emoji but STILL not have an comprehenisve set of frequently used icon symbols such as share... We still need custom icons for such common symbols but we don't need custom icons when we need to display rainbow pirates...

Comment: Dat was ingetogen Brits sarcasme, Stijn. ;-) Ik ben het met je eens.

Answer (score 2):

While the `share` symbol is not in the Unicode range, maybe this workaround will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/chillybang/a7v5obqj/

**HTML**

```
<span class="share">&lt;</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.share {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}
.share:before {
    content: ".";
    font-size: 2.2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.5px;
    left: -4px;
}
.share:after {
    content: ":";
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    right: -7px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Evgeniy - I also saw that jsFiddle before posting my question at the top. I agree that it's an adventurous attempt, but it's too unreliable. I don't know if it does look like a share icon in any other mobile or desktop browser, but in Firefox Desktop, the positioning of the left-hand dot is off.

Comment: if you really need this as icon, try an iconfont. My personal favorit is https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/share-variant

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy, that's cool. I'm probably going to stick with [Share Icon 2](https://github.com/RouninMedia/shodou/blob/master/user-interface/share2.svg).

Answer (score 1):

Its a hack, but it works

```
<span style="transform: rotate(90deg);">V</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Justin. Is this a new unicode symbol? Only, I can't find it anywhere - and I can't get it to show up in a CSS `::before` pseudo-element, either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one, but perhaps a megaphone would suffice: https://unicode-table.com/en/1F4E3/